# How to wrap a vector<T> in nanobind?

Tags: python, c++, nanobind

In `boost::python`, to wrap a `vector<T>` you would do something like this:

```
boost::python::class_< std::vector < T > >("T")
    .def(boost::python::vector_indexing_suite<std::vector< T > >());
```

How do I accomplish the same thing in nanobind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the header `<nanobind/stl/bind_vector.h>` and then its just:

```
nb::bind_vector<std::vector<T> >(m, "T");
```